# paypal integration morocco website

Tags: paypal, currency

I would like to integrate paypal to my website. I'm in Morocco. I saw only paypal accept 24 currencies.

1. So I want to know if it is possible to integrate paypal to my Moroccan site.
2. Should I convert to dollar amounts or there he has a method allowing me to manage my transactions Moroccan Dirhams?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See this link about recent arrange transfers between paypal and morocco bank:
http://www.middle-east-online.com/english/?id=69022